# How to use Context and Wakers when implementing Future in practice

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I am finding it difficult to understand why and when I need to explicitly do something with the `Context` and/or its `Waker` passed to the `poll` method on an object for which I am implementing `Future`. I have been reading the documentation from [Tokio](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/async#wakers) and the [Async Book](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/02_execution/03_wakeups.html), but I feel the examples/methods are too abstract to be applied to real problems.

For example, I would have thought the following MRE would deadlock since the future generated by `new_inner_task` would not know when a message has been passed on the MPSC channel, however, this example seems to work fine. Why is this the case?

```rust
use std::{future::Future, pin::Pin, task::{Context, Poll}, time::Duration};
use futures::{FutureExt, StreamExt}; // 0.3
use tokio::sync::mpsc; // 1.2
use tokio_stream::wrappers::UnboundedReceiverStream; // 0.1

async fn new_inner_task(rx: mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<()>) {
    let mut requests = UnboundedReceiverStream::new(rx);
    while let Some(_) = requests.next().await {
        eprintln!("received request");
    }
}

pub struct ActiveObject(Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>);

impl ActiveObject {
    pub fn new() -> (Self, mpsc::UnboundedSender<()>) {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::unbounded_channel();
        (Self(new_inner_task(rx).boxed()), tx)
    }
}

impl Future for ActiveObject {
    type Output = ();
    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        eprintln!("[polled]");
        self.get_mut().0.as_mut().poll(cx)
    }
}

async fn delayed_send(delay: u64, sender: mpsc::UnboundedSender<()>) {
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(delay)).await;
    sender.send(()).unwrap();
    eprintln!("sent request");
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (obj, tx) = ActiveObject::new();
    let ds = delayed_send(500, tx.clone());
    let ds2 = delayed_send(1000, tx);
    
    tokio::join!(obj, ds, ds2);
}
```

The output that I get from running this example locally is:

```
[polled]
[polled]
sent request
[polled]
received request
[polled]
sent request
[polled]
received request
```

So, although I haven't done anything with `Context` or `Waker`, `ActiveObject` appears to get polled at a reasonable rate, that is, more frequently than required, but not busy-waiting. What is causing `ActiveObject` to be woken up/polled at this rate?

Comment: The utilities provided by tokio obviously already are usable, they interact with the reactor/executor themselves. You can construct new Futures (which also is what you are doing with async functions) based on combinations of them, which is what your `ActiveObject` does. You only need to go into the details if you don't base your implementation on existing futures, e. g. when abstracting over operating system calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the same `Context` (and thus `Waker`) to the `poll()` method of the Future returned by `new_inner_task`, which passes it down the chain to the `poll()` of the `Future` returned by `UnboundedReceiverStream::next()`. The implementation of that arranges to call `wake()` on this `Waker` at the appropriate time (when new elements appear in the channel). When that is done, Tokio polls the top-level future associated with this `Waker` - the `join!()` of the three futures.

If you omitted the line that polls the inner task and just returned `Poll::Pending` instead, you would get the expected situation, where your `Future` would be polled once and then "hang" forever, as nothing would wake it again.

Comment: Could you add why `ActiveObject` gets polled twice (instead of once) after the first but before the second element has been put into the channel?

Comment: Looking at the [`join!()` macro](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.2.0/src/tokio/macros/join.rs.html#57-119), it seems that it shares the single `Context` among the futures and will poll each future  (`obj`, `ds`, `ds2`) every time it is woken. So it goes: 1. initial `poll()`; 2. `poll()` after `sleep()`; 3. `send()` happens and "send request" is printed, etc.